# What exactly is a skewed dataset ?

Tags: dataset

Like above, I'd like to know, what exactly a **skewed** dataset is.

The explanation from [stats.se.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231786/skewed-dataset-performance-measurement-in-machine-learning) sounds to me more like what I call an *imbalanced* dataset?

What is the distinction?

Comment: I would say in general skewed just means an asymmetrical distribution around the mean of the probability function: [Skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness). 

So I would rather use it for individual variables. However, if you say dataset you mean more than one variable?

Comment: It's better to call _distributions_ skewed and _datasets_ imbalanced to avoid confusion, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the link, a skewed data set is referring to a dataset with a class imbalance problem. They are trying to build a classifier, but they have many more negative examples than positive examples. It's not a very precise term, but I've heard to used in this context a few times.

Answer (score -1):

Skewed classes are scenarios where the number of observations belonging to one class are significantly lower than those belonging to other class. These occur commonly in electricity pilferage, fraudulent bank transaction etc. There are many techniques which can help to reduce this non-uniformity like SMOTE etc.